# Whats the proper way to access the data in a xml object

Tags: php, xml

I am working on a API project where i get an XML Object as a response. The response can contain one or more products in the NewOrder object(below).However when i try to display the info using a foreach loop it breaks if the only has one entry. i guess it is because the  index [0] does not exist in the object.how can i through the xml object and display since there is no [0] i the object. OR how do i add the index [0] in the object.

```
object(stdClass)#49 (1) {
["NewOrder"] => object(stdClass)#50 (12) {
["BTN"] => string(10) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx"
["PreOrderTransactionId"] => string(22) "XXXXXXXX"
["PartnerOrderId"] => string(17) "XXXXXXXXXXX"
["QwestOrderId"] => string(9) "N57395699"
["SalesCode"] => string(7) "XXXXXXXX"
["OrderStatus"] => string(7) "Pending"
["OrderStatusCode"] => string(4) "OPEN"
["OrderStatusSourceSystem"] => string(5) "CPLUS"
["OrderStatusMessage"] => string(0) ""
["OrderStatusDate"] => string(10) "2013-12-09"
["OrderStatusTime"] => string(8) "08:02:30"
["ProductFamily"] => array(3) {
  [0] => object(stdClass)#51 (2) {
    ["ProductFamilyName"] => string(7) "BUNDLE+"
    ["ProductLines"] => object(stdClass)#52 (3) {
      ["WTN"] => string(10) "3033689919"
      ["AppointmentDate"] => string(10) "2013-12-20"
      ["Products"] => object(stdClass)#53 (5) {
        ["ProductName"] => string(36) "INTERNET 100+ MBPS & HOME PHONE PLUS"
        ["Usoc"] => string(5) "BBBVC"
        ["Quantity"] => string(1) "1"
        ["Action"] => string(1) "I"
        ["Status"] => string(4) "OPEN"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
}
```

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
if (!is_array($this->Orders->NewOrder)) {
$this->Order->NewOrder = array($this->Orders->NewOrder["NewOrder"]);

}
foreach ($this->Orders->NewOrder as $order){?>
```

I am getting  the following error:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your NewOrder is only an array if it contains more than one object. Use something like this before your loop:

```
if (!is_array(yourObject["NewOrder"])) {
    yourObject["NewOrder"] = array(yourObject["NewOrder"]);
}
```

Comment: any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The SoapClient has an option that always creates the array, even if here is only one element.

```
return new SoapClient(
  '...',
  array(
    'location' => '...',
    /.../
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
  )
);
```